# Inner join and derived table

Tags: sql, inner-join, derived-table

I have been trying to solve Q9 from *SQL Movie-Rating Query Exercises* (*Find the difference between the average rating of movies released before 1980 and the average rating of movies released after 1980.* ). Due to the fact that almost every movie has more than one rating (stars) I need to calculate first average rating of each one. I'm doing this by this code:

```
SELECT 
     AVG(rating.stars) 
FROM Rating 
        INNER JOIN movie ON rating.mid = movie.mid 
GROUP BY 
     rating.mID 
HAVING 
     year < 1980
```

In the next step I put above code into the main query that will calculate difference between average rating before 1980 and after 1980. But first I want to see if everything will work well. Let's find out:

```
SELECT
    before.AVG_before1980
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
        AVG(rating.stars) as AVG_before1980
        FROM Rating 
            INNER JOIN movie ON rating.mid = movie.mid 
        GROUP BY rating.mID 
        HAVING year < 1980
    ) AS before
```

Output:

```
AVG_before1980
     3.0
     2.5
     4.5
```

Everything works fine so next step is to JOIN subquery which do same but after 1980 year:

```
SELECT
    before.AVG_before1980, after.AVG_after1980
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            AVG(rating.stars) as AVG_before1980
        FROM 
            Rating 
            INNER JOIN 
                    movie ON rating.mid = movie.mid 
        GROUP BY 
            rating.mID 
        HAVING 
            year < 1980
    ) AS before
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            AVG(rating.stars) as AVG_after1980
        FROM 
            Rating 
            INNER JOIN 
                    movie ON rating.mid = movie.mid 
        GROUP BY 
            rating.mID 
        HAVING 
            year > 1980
    ) AS after
```

Unfortunately output is not as I expected:

```
AVG_before_1980      AVG_after1980
     2.5                 4.0
     2.5                 3.33333333333333
     2.5                 2.5
     4.0                 4.0
     4.0                 3.33333333333333
     4.0                 2.5
     3.33333333333333    4.0
     3.33333333333333    3.33333333333333
```

I thought it would be:

```
AVG_before1980   AVG_after1980
    3.0              2.5
    2.5              4.0
    4.5          3.33333333333333
```

Question is simple: What I have to do to get above output? It would be nice if someone could explain me more what am I doing wrong. And please feel free to improve my code.

All needed tabels: https://lagunita.stanford.edu/c4x/DB/SQL/asset/moviedata.html

Comment: In the link you provided there are 8 movies: 5 before 1980 and 3 after 1980. Can you explain why your expected result is 3 rows? What average is each row?

Comment: To solve this whole exercise I need to first know the average rating (stars column) of each movie **from 'Review' table**. If you look at 'Review' table you see that almost every movie (mID column) has two or more rating (stars column). For example movie with mID 104 has  been rated 2 times: 2, 3; movie with mid 108 has 3 stars: 4, 2, 4 etc. Just use this code: `SELECT DISTINCT mid FROM rating` and you will see that every movie that is in 'Movie' table not necessarily is in the rating table.

Comment: I see that. What I don't understand is why you expect 3 rows a result? I think the solution is 1 row with 2 columns. The 1st column is the average of the movies before 1980 and the 2nd column the average of the movies after 1980. So 2 numbers, just like Gordon's answer.

Comment: Ah ok, I get what you mean. I just asked about what I don't understand. I know how to make main SELECT clause but I don't know why after JOINED my second subqery (i.e.  after 1980) I get output like you can see above.

Comment: You are doing an inner join without an ON clause. This results in a CROSS JOIN between the rows of the 2 queries. So if the 1st query returns 3 rows and the 2nd query returns 5 rows then the result will be all the possible combinations: 3x5 = 15 rows.

Comment: Thanks! But what I have to do in order to get result I need (2 columns with 3 rows each)? I mean on what conditions connect these two subqueries?

Comment: This result is what I don't understand. Say for the 1st row. What is 3.0 and 2.0? How is 3.0 related to 2.0? Why not 3.0, 4.0?

Comment: I think my whole approach to this exercise was bad ;/. I was thinking that maybe somehow I will put results from _before and after 1980_ queries into this : `SELECT AVG(my_column_from_before_1980_query) - AVG(my_column_from_after_1980_query).`

Comment: You can if you want only 1 row. Rethink about your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the average of *ratings* on movies before and after 1980:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN m.year < 1980 THEN r.stars END) as avg_pre1980,
       AVG(CASE WHEN m.year > 1980 THEN r.stars END) as avg_post1980
FROM Rating r INNER JOIN
     movie m
     ON r.mid = m.mid ;
```

To get the average for *movies*, you need to aggregate first by movie and then overall:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN m.year < 1980 THEN avg_stars END) as avg_pre1980,
       AVG(CASE WHEN m.year > 1980 THEN avg_stars END) as avg_post1980
FROM (SELECT m.id, year, AVG(r.stars) as avg_stars
      FROM Rating r INNER JOIN
           movie m
           ON r.mid = m.mid
      GROUP BY m.id, m.year
     ) my
```

You don't specify your database, but some use integer arithmetic for division and averages, so you should convert to a non-integer number to get a more accurate average:  `AVG(r.stars * 1.0)`.